# Label at a toolbar

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, label, toolbar

Is it possible to use a label at a toolbar?
I would like to display a number in a label. It is easy in a view but now I want it to be displayed in the toolbar.
I can drag a label to the toolbar, no problem, but the content is not visible there, even if the name Label is visible in the IB.

More info: If I drag a label into toolbar on an single view it works perfectly to display any text or number in the label even in the toolbar.
But the problem I seem to have is it does not work at a toolbar if the view is a scrollview!!
Buttons, bar buttons, no problem, but just the label does not show up when I run the app.

Why are the toolbar items behaving differently if the view is a scrollview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better not to use a label for a toolbar but a UIBarButtonItem. Then you select in IB plain style and you can display the text in title.